# jquery styling not working in react component

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

jQuery seems to be working fine in react component however, when I try to apply styling using jquery in react component its not working. In the below code `console.log(eachVisitedTopic)` within each loop is returning proper result as expected.

```
topicsVisited(arr){
     $(function() {
      $.each(arr, function(key, eachVisitedTopic) {
        console.log(eachVisitedTopic);
        $('.single-topic[data-topic-id="' + eachVisitedTopic + '"]').css({
          'background-color': 'red'
        });
      });
    });
  };
```

**Markup**

```
import {React, ReactDOM} from '../../../../build/react';

export default class SingleTopicBox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="col-sm-2">
          <div className="single-topic" data-topic-id={this.props.topicID} onClick={() => this.props.onClick(this.props.topicID)}>
            {this.props.label}
            {this.props.topicID}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Could you give an example of your react markup?

Comment: I think you should use `style` attribute for that. It's more powerful way to handle the states of styles.

Comment: @FatihErikli I've added the markup, can you please show an example for my case.

Answer (score 3):

React should handle all the render, it checks the dirty dom and render only things that changed.

You can achieve what you want, just use a react state.
When you trigger a setState change react will look into the DOM and find what has changed and then render it.

Ref: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            bgDisplayColor: "blue"
        };
    }
```

Then you can do something like this in yout component:

```
$('.single-topic[data-topic-id="' + eachVisitedTopic + '"]').css({
          'background-color': this.state.bgDisplayColor
        });
```

And to update it you simply use:

```
this.setState({bgDisplayColor: "red"});
```

**EDIT**

To workaround the undefined variable error, you have to store the scope of "this" inside your function and use instead of "this", because inside the jquery .css "this" refers to Jquery and not the "this" scope of your actual class.

Example:

```
topicsVisited(arr){
   var self = this;
   $(function(){
      $.each(arr, function(key, eachVisitedTopic){
         console.log(eachVisitedTopic);
         //self here is the global scope of your class
         //Inside jQuery.css this refers to Jquery and not to your class.
         $('.single-topic[data-topic-id="' + eachVisitedTopic + '"]').css({
                  'background-color': self.state.bgDisplayColor
                });
        });
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bgDisplayColor' of undefined`

Comment: You 're probably inside the scope of jquery, I'll post a solution in edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try it to by putting all jQuery code inside the componentDidMount
E.g :

```
      componentDidMount() {
         //Your jQuery function goes here 
      }
```